# PLS-00201: identifier UTIL_FILE must be declared

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to export data from a query into a csv file from Oracle Enterprise Express installed on a Windows Server 2008 machine.

I've found this solution:

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:235814350980

which basically writes a function and uses the UTIL_FILE object to create and write to a file and add delimiters.

I receive the follow error when I try and create the function in Oracle SQL Developer:

```
PLS-00201: identifier UTIL_FILE must be declared.
```

When I run the following command:

```
select owner, object_type from all_objects where object_name = 'UTL_FILE'
```

The result is:

```
OWNER      Object Type
---------  -----------
PUBLIC     SYNONYM
```

EDIT:

Running:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON UTL_FILE TO PUBLIC
```

Gives:

```
Error starting at line 2 in command:
GRANT EXECUTE ON UTL_FILE TO PUBLIC
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Connecting as SYS user with SYSDBA privileges has solved the problem. I was able to execute the GRANT command on my user, then I had the required privileges

Answer (score 13):

Seems like lack of privileges to me. Often `PUBLIC` user has `EXECUTE` privilege granted on that package, but the privilege may be revoked.

You can check if `PUBLIC` has that privilege by issuing the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM all_tab_privs WHERE grantee = 'PUBLIC' AND table_name = 'UTL_FILE';
```

If there are no rows returned, try granting the execute privilege to either the user you are logged as, or to `PUBLIC`, as some privileged user, for example `SYS`:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.utl_file TO user_name;
```

**Edit**

You must grant the privilege while being logged as, for example, `SYS` user.

Comment: Error starting at line 2 in command:
GRANT EXECUTE ON UTL_FILE TO mobilewalletdb
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @KristyWelsh Are you logged as `SYS` user?

Comment: SELECT * FROM all_tab_privs WHERE grantee = 'PUBLIC' AND table_name = 'UTL_FILE' gives no records.

Comment: @KristyWelsh You must grant this privilege as a `SYS` user, or some other user with enough privileges. If the database is managed by somebody else, ask the administrator to grant that privilege to `PUBLIC`. If you have access to `SYS` account, just log as `SYS` and issue the command to grant the privilege to `PUBLIC`.

Comment: Applied for privledges - we will see.

Answer (score 2):

Users do not have execute permission on UTL_FILE by default. To use UTL_FILE, an ADMIN user or instance administrator must explicitly GRANT EXECUTE permission on it, such as in the following example:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.UTL_FILE TO scott;
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the possible lack of permissions that other answers have covered, your question says the error you get is:

```
PLS-00201: identifier UTIL_FILE must be declared
```

That suggests you've referenced `UTIL_FILE`, rather than the built-in package `UTL_FILE`, in your function. It might be an error you've introduced writing the question, of course, but you used it in the text too so maybe you have got the package name wrong in your code, if you didn't just copy-and-paste Tom's code.

You'll still need execute privileges on `UTL_FILE` anyway, if you don't have them already.

Comment: It was a typo in my question.  The script correctly references UTL_FILE.  Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1):

As user: h_djebli pointed out in his comment you need to be connected as SYS user in the first place.

To do that, you have to be in your oracle home directory :

```
cd $ORACLE_HOME
```

Then execute :

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

sqlplus will start in your terminal and you'll be connected as the SYS user.

You can finally write the GRANT command in your sqlplus console :

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.utl_file TO your_db_username;
```

Answer (score -1):

We can do this via cmd, with these steps:

1. Login as `sysdba` (`connect sys as sysdba` + enter password as sys_password)
2. `grant execute on utl_file to <user_name>`.
3. now we can check by query :`'SELECT * FROM all_tab_privs WHERE grantee = 'PUBLIC' AND table_name = 'UTL_FILE';'`

Comment: Are you sure this answers the question? The author needs csv ecport, which is clearly not achieved here.